# solvablity for some polynomial 

Tags: galois-theory

We know that if F is a field which ch(F)=0,p(x) is a polynomial with coefficient of F,then p(x)root solvablity if and only if the Galois group of p(x) is solvablity .Here I want to know if the character of F is not zero ,how to judge the root solvablity ?Is there a analogue theorem?

Comment: You need separability conditions, but given thos, the theory is much the same in characteristics other than $2$ and $3$.

Comment: When you say "root solvability", perhaps you mean "solvable by radicals".  In prime characteristic $p$, you will have to replace (for example) the radical $\root p\of$ by the "Artin-Schreier radical" $\wp_p^{-1}(\ )$, where $\wp_p^{-1}(a)$ stands for a root of $T^p-T-a$, etc.  Apart from such obvious changes, the theory should be the same as in characteristic $0$.  See for example http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81989/solving-the-cubic-by-radicals-in-characteristics-2-and-3

Comment: @Geoff Robinson: what is different about characteristics 2 and 3?